# Is there a way to use ApplicationEventPublisher with delayed event in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration, spring-messaging

I would need to use event-driven mechanism. using `ApplicationEventPublisher`. I would want to set a delay for the message before reach to the endpoint that listening to this event. Is there such a way? found https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.RC1/reference/html/delayer.html but not sure how it should integrate with ApplicationEventPublisher.

Is there a simple way to use spring to achieve the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the `Delayer`, Spring Integration also provides `ApplicationEventPublishingMessageHandler` to producer an `ApplicationEvent` to the `ApplicationEventPublisher` based on the incoming message. This way you really will delay the message (an event) in the `<delayer>` and then publish an event to the application via `<int-event:outbound-channel-adapter>`.

Also consider to use as late Spring Integration version as possible: https://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/